# animated eyes: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, console

this is my first time asking a question on here so if I do this "wrong" please let me know. Im trying to implement a moving eyes on a face animation like in the video [here](https://youtu.be/TGe3pS5LqEw) (who doesnt love fireship?). Im trying to make it my own so its 1 base img and 1 set of eyes. the '.getBoundingClientRect' is giving me the above error in the console. does anyone have any ideas as to why this is or how I can fix? thanks in advance!

the code:

```
import React from "react";
import "./MovingFounder.css";

class MovingFounder extends React.Component {
    render() {
        document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
            const mouseX = e.clientX;
            const mouseY = e.clientY;

            const anchor = document.getElementById('anchor');
            const rekt = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();
            
            const anchorX = rekt.left + rekt.width / 2;
            const anchorY = rekt.top + rekt.height / 2;
            const angleDeg = angle(mouseX, mouseY, anchorX, anchorY);

            console.log(angleDeg);

            const eyes = document.querySelector(".founder-eyes");
            eyes.forEach((eye) => {
                eye.style.transform = `rotate(${angleDeg}deg)`;
            })
        });

        function angle(cx, cy, ex, ey) {
            const dy = ey - cy;
            const dx = ex - cx;
            const rad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
            const deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI);
            return deg;

        }

        return (
            <div class="founder-moving">
                <img class="anchor" src="./images/noeyes-founder.png" alt="founder body" />
                <div>
                    <img class="founder-eyes" src="./images/founder-eyes.png" alt="founder eyes" />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}



export default MovingFounder;
```

Comment: just correcting the line `const rekt = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();` with `const rekt = anchor?.getBoundingClientRect();` should be working.

Comment: how does that help? You just delegate the problem to the next line since rekt will be null no? Also, I think he doesn't expect anchor to be undefined to begin with.

Comment: @MissSkooter I'm offering a solution for the error titled with this question and the code part shown. I don't need to tell every possibility even I know it without enquirer ask explicitly. So that, I didn't make it an answer. And you should better mention someone if you intend to respond their comment.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar if your solution causes an error in literally the next line then it's not really a solution...

Answer (score 0):

It is `null` because you are `querying` an element with `id` `anchor` that doesn't exist in the `DOM`. Add `id` to one of your `img` element

```
import React from "react";
// import "./MovingFounder.css";

class MovingFounder extends React.Component {
  render() {
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      const mouseX = e.clientX;
      const mouseY = e.clientY;

      const anchor = document.getElementById("anchor");
      const rekt = anchor.getBoundingClientRect();

      const anchorX = rekt.left + rekt.width / 2;
      const anchorY = rekt.top + rekt.height / 2;
      const angleDeg = angle(mouseX, mouseY, anchorX, anchorY);

      console.log(angleDeg);

      const eyes = document.querySelectorAll(".founder-eyes");
      eyes?.forEach((eye) => {
        eye.style.transform = `rotate(${angleDeg}deg)`;
      });
    });

    function angle(cx, cy, ex, ey) {
      const dy = ey - cy;
      const dx = ex - cx;
      const rad = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
      const deg = rad * (180 / Math.PI);
      return deg;
    }

    return (
      <div className="founder-moving">

        <img
          className="anchor"
         //Here I have added id
          id="anchor"
          src="./images/noeyes-founder.png"
          alt="founder body"
        />
        <div>
          <img
            //Also change class to className in React
            className="founder-eyes"
            src="./images/founder-eyes.png"
            alt="founder eyes"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MovingFounder;
```